# iOS AudioUnit garbage input and output callback error on writing to right channel

Tags: ios, core-audio, exc-bad-access, audiounit

I'm trying to output a sine wave on the left channel and silence on the right channel of an `AudioUnit`. I receive the following error when trying to write zero to the right channel,

```
Thread 5: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)
```

The callback function where this occurs is below with the line where the error is occuring marked by the comment `/ **** ERROR HERE ****` at the end of the line

**Output Callback**

```
static OSStatus outputCallback(void *inRefCon,
                          AudioUnitRenderActionFlags    *ioActionFlags,
                          const AudioTimeStamp          *inTimeStamp,
                          UInt32                        inBusNumber,
                          UInt32                        inNumberFrames,
                          AudioBufferList               *ioData) {
    // Scope reference to GSFSensorIOController class
    GSFSensorIOController *THIS = (__bridge GSFSensorIOController *) inRefCon;

    // Communication out on left and right channel if new communication out
    AudioSampleType *outLeftSamples = (AudioSampleType *) ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
    AudioSampleType *outRightSamples = (AudioSampleType *) ioData->mBuffers[1].mData;

    // Set up power tone attributes
    float freq = 20000.00f;
    float sampleRate = 44100.00f;
    float phase = THIS.sinPhase;
    float sinSignal;

    double phaseInc = 2 * M_PI * freq / sampleRate;

    for (UInt32 curFrame = 0; curFrame < inNumberFrames; ++curFrame) {
        // Generate power tone on left channel
        sinSignal = sin(phase);
        outLeftSamples[curFrame] = (SInt16) ((sinSignal * 32767.0f) /2);
        outRightSamples[curFrame] = (SInt16) (0);   // **** ERROR HERE ****
        phase += phaseInc;
        if (phase >= 2 * M_PI * freq) {
            phase = phase - (2 * M_PI * freq);
        }
    }

    // Save sine wave phase wave for next callback
    THIS.sinPhase = phase;

    return noErr;
}
```

The `curFrame = 0` and `outRightSamples = NULL` at the time the error is thrown. This leads me to believe that I'm setting up the channels incorrectly. Here is where I set up the IO of my AudioUnit,

**Audio Unit Set Up**

```
// Audio component description
AudioComponentDescription desc;
desc.componentType          = kAudioUnitType_Output;
desc.componentSubType       = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
desc.componentManufacturer  = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
desc.componentFlags         = 0;
desc.componentFlagsMask     = 0;

// Get component
AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

// Mono ASBD
AudioStreamBasicDescription monoStreamFormat;
monoStreamFormat.mSampleRate          = 44100.00;
monoStreamFormat.mFormatID            = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
monoStreamFormat.mFormatFlags         = kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical;
monoStreamFormat.mBytesPerPacket      = 2;
monoStreamFormat.mBytesPerFrame       = 2;
monoStreamFormat.mFramesPerPacket     = 1;
monoStreamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame    = 1;
monoStreamFormat.mBitsPerChannel      = 16;

// Stereo ASBD
AudioStreamBasicDescription stereoStreamFormat;
stereoStreamFormat.mSampleRate          = 44100.00;
stereoStreamFormat.mFormatID            = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
stereoStreamFormat.mFormatFlags         = kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical;
stereoStreamFormat.mBytesPerPacket      = 4;
stereoStreamFormat.mBytesPerFrame       = 4;
stereoStreamFormat.mFramesPerPacket     = 1;
stereoStreamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame    = 2;
stereoStreamFormat.mBitsPerChannel      = 16;

OSErr err;
@try {
    // Get Audio units
    err = AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &_ioUnit);
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error setting input component: %hd", err);

    // Enable input, which is disabled by default. Output is enabled by default
    UInt32 enableInput = 1;
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(_ioUnit,
                         kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                         kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                         kInputBus,
                         &enableInput,
                         sizeof(enableInput));
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error enable input: %hd", err);

    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(_ioUnit,
                         kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                         kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                         kOutputBus,
                         &enableInput,
                         sizeof(enableInput));
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error setting output: %hd", err);

    // Apply format to input of ioUnit
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.ioUnit,
                         kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                         kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                         kOutputBus,
                         &monoStreamFormat,
                         sizeof(monoStreamFormat));
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error setting input ASBD: %hd", err);

    // Apply format to output of ioUnit
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.ioUnit,
                         kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                         kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                         kInputBus,
                         &stereoStreamFormat,
                         sizeof(stereoStreamFormat));
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error setting output ASBD: %hd", err);

    // Set input callback
    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
    callbackStruct.inputProc = inputCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.ioUnit,
                         kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback,
                         kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                         kInputBus,
                         &callbackStruct,
                         sizeof(callbackStruct));
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error setting input callback: %hd", err);

    // Set output callback
    callbackStruct.inputProc = outputCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.ioUnit,
                         kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                         kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                         kOutputBus,
                         &callbackStruct,
                         sizeof(callbackStruct));
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error setting output callback: %hd", err);

    // Disable buffer allocation
    UInt32 disableBufferAlloc = 0;
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(self.ioUnit,
                               kAudioUnitProperty_ShouldAllocateBuffer,
                               kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                               kInputBus,
                               &disableBufferAlloc,
                               sizeof(disableBufferAlloc));

    // Allocate input buffers (1 channel, 16 bits per sample, thus 16 bits per frame and therefore 2 bytes per frame
    _inBuffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
    _inBuffer.mDataByteSize = 512 * 2;
    _inBuffer.mData = malloc( 512 * 2 );

    // Initialize audio unit
    err = AudioUnitInitialize(self.ioUnit);
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error initializing unit: %hd", err);
    //AudioUnitInitialize(self.ioUnit);

    // Start audio IO
    err = AudioOutputUnitStart(self.ioUnit);
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error starting unit: %hd", err);
    //AudioOutputUnitStart(self.ioUnit);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Failed with exception: %@", exception);
}
```

I don't believe I'm setting up the AudioUnit correctly because I'm getting random values for my input on the mic line (ie. printing the input buffers to the command prompt gives values that do not change with ambient noise). Here's how I'm using my input callback,

**Input Callback**

```
static OSStatus inputCallback(void *inRefCon,
                               AudioUnitRenderActionFlags   *ioActionFlags,
                               const AudioTimeStamp         *inTimeStamp,
                               UInt32                       inBusNumber,
                               UInt32                       inNumberFrames,
                               AudioBufferList              *ioData) {
    // Scope reference to GSFSensorIOController class
    GSFSensorIOController *THIS = (__bridge GSFSensorIOController *) inRefCon;

    // Set up buffer to hold input data
    AudioBuffer buffer;
    buffer.mNumberChannels = 1;
    buffer.mDataByteSize = inNumberFrames * 2;
    buffer.mData = malloc( inNumberFrames * 2 );

    // Place buffer in an AudioBufferList
    AudioBufferList bufferList;
    bufferList.mNumberBuffers = 1;
    bufferList.mBuffers[0] = buffer;

    // Grab the samples and place them in the buffer list
    AudioUnitRender(THIS.ioUnit,
                    ioActionFlags,
                    inTimeStamp,
                    inBusNumber,
                    inNumberFrames,
                    &bufferList);

    // Process data
    [THIS processIO:&bufferList];

    // Free allocated buffer
    free(bufferList.mBuffers[0].mData);

    return noErr;
}
```

I've searched for example projects, as a reference, and I can't see a difference in the over all implementation of functionality. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Audio Unit default setting may be for interleaved stereo channel data rather separate buffers for left and right.

Comment: @hotpaw2- That's what I assumed but when I add `kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved` to the ASBD (of either/both the input or output) I get the error code 29759 during `AudioUnitInitialize(self.ioUnit)`. I can't seem to find any documentation on this error code either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here looks to be that you're writing to unallocated memory. ioData->mBuffers[1] isn't valid for interleaved format. Both left and right channels are interleaved in ioData->mBuffers[0]. If you want non-interleaved data, mBytesPerFrame and mBytesPerPacket should be 2, not 4. That's probably why you're failing on AudioUnitInitialize for that format.

It's easier to deal with setting up these formats if you use the CAStreamBasicDescription utility class. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CoreAudioUtilityClasses/Introduction/Intro.html.

Setting up AudioStreamBasicDescription would then be as easy as:

```
CAStreamBasicDescription stereoStreamFormat(44100.0, 2, CAStreamBasicDescription::kPCMFormatInt16, false);
```

Comment: Thanks again for your response. So if I change the `mBytesPerFrame` and `mBytesPerPacket` to 2 then the channels are no longer interleaved, how does that work? I'm not seeing the connection from the Apple docs on `AudioUnit` 's. Also how do I access the buffers associated with each channel once they are non-interleaved? Am I at least doing that part correctly in the current version of my code? I have not heard of `CAStreamBasicDescription` but I just looked at the iOS docs. From the Apple example code I'm not seeing how each channel is accessed with `CAStreamBasicDescription`

Comment: CAStreamBasicDescription is just a convenience class for configuring an AudioStreamBasicDescription struct. It subclasses AudioStreamBasicDescription so you can pass it in when you call AudioUnitSetProperty to set the format.  If the data is non-interleaved then your code should work from what I can tell. ioData->mBuffers[1] will contain the 2nd channel of audio.

Comment: Alternatively you can leave the data as interleaved and just write the output to ioData->mBuffers[0]. Just write the sine wave data to every other sample, with zeroes in between. The size of the buffer at ioData->mBuffers[0] will be twice the number of frames.

Comment: Changing `mBytesPerFrame` and `mBytesPerPacket` to 2 did not make the channels non-interleaved. The same error occurs on the same line. I tried leaving the ASBD unchanged and alternating writing the sine wave and zeros to every other sample does not yield the desired result. When I try using `CAStreamBasicDescription` in place of the ASBD I get an unknown reference to `CAStreamBasicDesciption` and a suggestion to use ASBD instead.

Comment: I've read some where that setting the output on an AudioUnit is pointless because the AudioUnit uses the ASBD for the input across the output. Although this seems wrong to me I can't seem to disprove it. Do you know if there is any truth to this claim? If that is the case then I just want to set up my input and output as stereo and still need to know how to access both channels independently.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by unknown reference. Linker error? Did you included the CAStreamBasicDesciption.cpp source file in your project? It should be no problem to use this class as it's a subclass of ASBD... Also, in addition to setting `mBytesPerFrame` and `mBytesPerPacket` to 2 you need to also need to add `kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved` to the ASBD. You really should let CAStreamBasicDesciption handle setting up these formats if at all possible.... so easy to get these wrong. Not true what you read.. that said, get it working with stereo in, stereo out first.